# Play option not working in SlidesJS?

Tags: jquery, autoplay, slidesjs

According to the SlidesJS docs, you should be able to set the autoplay speed by setting the "play" option, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-slideshow').slides({
        effect : 'fade',
        crossfade : true,
        fadeSpeed : 1000,
        play: 5000,   <------------------------- Autoplay interval
        pause : 2500, <-------- What?
        hoverPause : true
    });
});
```

It's not working, it doesn't autoplay at al. I also don't understand the difference between "pause" and "play".

According to doc:

**play (number):**

> Autoplay slideshow, a positive number will set to true and be **the
>   time between slide animation** in milliseconds.

**pause(number):**

> Pause slideshow on click of next/prev or pagination. A positive number
>   will set to true and be **the time of pause** in milliseconds.

I don't get it, what's the difference? Neither of them seem to do anything as of right now though.

What am i missing?

Doc is here:
http://www.slidesjs.com/#docs

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that the slideshow is actually working. jQuery is imported etc and the slideshow works when i click the nav buttons. It's just the autoplay not working.

**EDIT**
Made a JSFiddle, not working there either.
http://jsfiddle.net/WbGeL/

**Solution**
The hoverPause option does not work as expected. As soon as i hover overthe webpage (anywhere really) it thinks i'm hovering over the slideshow. Even if i move the mouse out of the entire browser it still thinks i'm hovering, which causes the autoplay not to work.

Comment: Are you sure that your slideshow html markup is correct, and that you have added correct css? Any errors in JavaScript console?

Comment: Yup, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post get javascript error ??

You should do following things are:-

1) Include jQuery file.
2) Include Sliders plugin js file.

Comment: you should add comment if you are giving this type of answer?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
      autoplay: true;
```

I think the play setting is for the slide duration.

Comment: What! That's not specified anywhere in the doc file, is it? Frustrating, that should be included very clearly. And no, fadeSpeed or slideSpeed is for the slide duration. play is for the pause between the autoplay, but pause i have no idea what it does.

Comment: Oh, now it seems to not work again. It worked once, then stopped working after i replied. I didn't change anything. autoplay seems to do nothing, and it's not specified in the doc so i don't think it exists? Maybe it's just a bug in the lib?

Comment: is this on a server somewhere?

Comment: Nope, running locally unfortunately. There's not much to see though. No errors in console, and my code is in the OP. Anything else you want to see? I strongly doubt HTML is the issue since the slideshow actually works, it's just one single option refusing to work.

Comment: Works for me too now. I found that the hoverPause option is very unconsistent and don't work as it should. As soon as i disabled it it works for me again.

Answer (score 0):

your fiddle didn't work because 'slidejs' wasn't loaded (it's not part of jQuery). So I pasted the minified version above your javascript and made a couple tweaks.

Essentially, your code was fine. If you're going to use hoverPause you MUST include the pause parameter to 'restart' the slides.

Only modified your .slides params:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').slides({
        effect : 'fade',
        crossfade : true,
        fadeSpeed : 1000,
        play: 5000, //  <---- Wait to start and slide change interval.
        hoverPause : true,
        // miliseconds to wait before resume play on mouseout (hoverPause).
        pause : 10
    });
});
```

Here's the modified fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WbGeL/7/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but I did some sleuthing and found that the `play` option takes an object containing various playback options. From my understanding, `play` is mainly for triggering a slideshow based on a play/stop button, but it does have an `auto` option that turns on the autoplay:

```
play: {
    active: false,        // Don't display play/stop button
    auto: true,           // Activates autoplay
    effect: "fade",
    interval: 5000       // Time between slides
},
```

Hope that helps!